# Can't connect to database to update member details

Tags: php, mysql

I can't connect to my database while running this page on submitting updated details.  For the life of me can't figure out why it wont connect.

Most recent error:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'MattS1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in F:\xampp\htdocs\Site\ProfileUpdate.php on line 69 cannot connect

Below is the db.inc file details as well, since it has no password i have no clue why this error is being posted.

My db.inc file is:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename= "schurter_products";
```

PHP/SQL:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require 'db.inc';


  // Initialise an error string
  $errorString = "";

  // trim the POSTed values - gets rid of unecessary whitespace 
   $firstname = trim($_POST["Firstname"]);
   $surname   = trim($_POST["Surname"]);
   $emailaddress   = trim($_POST["Emailaddress"]);
   $username    = trim($_POST["Username"]);
   $password    = trim($_POST["Password"]);
  //Here we use validation at the server
  // Vaildate the firstname

  if (empty($firstname)) 
      // First name cannot be a null string
      $errorString .=
          "\n<br>The first name field cannot be blank.";

  // Validate the Surname
  if (empty($surname))
      // the user's surname cannot be a null string
      $errorString .=
          "\n<br>The surname field cannot be blank.";

  // Validate the email Address
  if (empty($emailaddress))
      // the user's address cannot be a null string
      $errorString .=
          "\n<br>You must supply at least one address line.";

  // Validate the username
  if (empty($username))
      // the user's city cannot be a null string
      $errorString .= "\n<br>You must supply a city.";

  // Validate password
  if (empty($password))
      // the user's city cannot be a null string
      $errorString .= "\n<br>You must supply state.";


  // Now the script has finished the validation, 
  // check if there were any errors
  if (!empty($errorString))
  {
      // There are errors.  Show them and exit.
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
   "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
<html>
<head><title>Customer Details Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">  
<h1>Customer Details Error</h1>
<?=$errorString?>
<br><a href="updateInsertForm.php">Return to the customer form</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php     

  }
  else
  {
   // If we made it here, then the data is valid
mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$databasename")or die("cannot select DB");

//  this is an update


       $query = "UPDATE members SET Firstname = '$firstname', Surname = '$surname', Emailadress = '$emailaddress', Username = '$username', Password = '$password' WHERE id = '$memberID'";


        $recordSet = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

        echo "Your updates are complete!"; 

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
 mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
 mysql_select_db("$databasename")or die("cannot select DB");
```

to

```
 mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($databasename)or die(mysql_error());
```

- don't use quotes here around variables.
- better use `mysql_error()` for better debugging to know what the error is. If you print `cannot connect` you don't know what the error is, just the string.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I had that before and copped what was working on another page.  Still the same error of 

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'MattS1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in F:\xampp\htdocs\Site\ProfileUpdate.php on line 69
cannot connect

Comment: if your error `Access denied for user 'MattS1'@'localhost` then verfiy your credential , user and password .

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin and I've gone into the privileges tab on my DB and everything looks ok, all are granted and nothing looks out of place (I'm assuming this is what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Haha sorry, but I see your problem. You overwrite your username :)

```
$username = "root";
```

and

```
$username    = trim($_POST["Username"]);
```

Hence the error for this user:

> Access denied for user 'MattS1'@'localhost'

Rather than user "root".

Comment: AH! So renaming this variable should fix it?

Comment: as it goes now, you are logging in with the username provided via the form :) So yes, you should change one of the $username to something else (and of course change them too on other parts where you use this variable).

Comment: OK I changed in my db.inc file to $user instead of $username and kept the variables the same.  changed it on all my pages too, and its working fine for product pages and every other page EXCEPT updating details.  Still same error ,still wont work. :S

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You do just the same with the variable `$password`. Please consider to replace the outdated mysql_ extension with a modern API like mysqli or PDO, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php. Sanitizing your database inputs, i.e. use of prepared statements, will remedy the possibility of sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$databasename")or die("cannot select DB");
```

You should remove the speechmarks between each variable, check that the MySQL user and MySQL database are connected and have valid permissions, check also that the MySQL user password is correct and that there is no prefix for username or databasename. Example, if you are using cPanel and your username is foo, it would be foo_root and foo_schurter_products

Just a pro-tip, MySQL is deprecated in later version of PHP and you are prompted to use MySQLi.